# the pythonic way of optional imports

Tags: python, import

I have a package that allows the user to use any one of 4 packages they want to connect to a database. It works great but I'm unhappy with the way I'm importing things.

I could simply import all the packages, but I don't want to do that in case the specific user doesn't ever need to use `turbodbc` for example:

```
import pyodbc
import pymssql
import turbodbc
from ibmdbpy.base import IdaDataBase
```

Currently, I have the following situation. I try to import all of them, but the ones that don't import, no problem, My program simply assumes they will not be called and if they are it errors:

```
# some envs may not have all these packages installed so we try each:

try:
    import pyodbc
except:
    pass

try:
    import pymssql
except:
    pass

try:
    import turbodbc
except:
    pass

try:
    from ibmdbpy.base import IdaDataBase
except:
    pass
```

This doesn't feel pythonic. So I know there are packages such as holoviews or tensorflow that allow you to specify a backend. They are of course orders of magnitude more complicated than mine, but they have to handle the same pattern.

How can I make this code right? it is technically buggy because if they intend to use `pyodbc` but don't have it installed, my program will not warn them, it will error at runtime. So really this goes beyond esthetics or philosophy; this is technically error-prone code.

How would you handle this situation?

Fyi, here is an example of how the code is called:

```
connect('Playground', package='pymssql')
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
try: 
    import pyodbc
except ImportError: 
    pyodbc = None
```

then later:

```
if pyodbc is None and user_wants_to_use_pyodbc:
    print_warning()
    raise SomeConfigurationErrorOrSuch()
```

This approach works well for a small number of options.  If you have enough options that you need to abstract out this approach, then you can use the `importlib` module to import modules under the control of your program.

Comment: I still don't believe the ideal solution has been provided amongst any of the answers, but thanks sam, yours was the solution I went with, it seemed to serve my purposes the best. later in my code like you suggested I did this: `return locals()[f'use_{package}_db2']() if package in ['pyodbc','IdaDataBase'] and package is not None else raise ValueError(f'{package} module not imported. Please pip install.')`

Comment: Another good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27361558/3699361

Answer (score 4):

I would use import_module from importlib:

```
from importlib import import_module

modules_to_import = ['pyodbc', 'pymssql', 'turbodbc', 'ibmdbpy.base.IdaDataBase']
for m in modules_to_import:
    try:
        globals()[m.split('.')[-1]] = import_module(m)
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        print('Module {} not found'.format(m))
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used something similar to the answers above, but sometimes you might need to mock an object to fool lint.

```
try:
    from neuralprophet import NeuralProphet
    using_neuralprophet = True
except ImportError:
    class NeuralMock:
       whatever=False
    using_neuralprophet = False
    NeuralProphet = NeuralMock()
```

Source: [timemachines](https://github.com/microprediction/timemachines/blob/main/timemachines/skaters/nproph/nprophetinclusion.py)

Answer (score 0):

You can put imports in places other than the beginning of the file.  "Re-importing" something doesn't actually do anything, so it's not computationally expensive to `import x` frequently:

```
def switch(x):
    if x == 'a':
        import json
        json.load(file)
    elif x == 'b':
        import pandas as pd
        pd.read_csv(file)
```

You can also use `importlib` to dynamically import modules.  This is especially useful if you have multiple implementations of the same API that you want to choose between

```
class Connection:
    def __init__(self, driver_module, driver_name):
        # or driver_module, driver_name = full_path.rsplit('.', 1)
        self.driver = get_attr(importlib.load_module(driver_module), driver_name)()
    def method(self):
        return self.driver.do()
```